# Навигация по постам в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть родительская рубрика магазины, в ней несколько дочерних рубрик с записями.

Как сделать навигацию следующего/предыдущего постов так, чтобы эта навигация была только внутри этих дочерних рубрик, не выходя за их пределы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php get_next_post( $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy ) ?>
<?php get_previous_post( $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy ) ?>
```

Первый же параметр означает - в этой же категории или нет.

Подробнее в [кодексе](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post).

Comment: Мне нужно исключить главную (родительскую) категорию из навигации, переходя по постам которые приходятся непосредственными родителями записи

Comment: второй параметр — `$excluded_terms`

Answer (score 0):

Сделал с помощью плагина [Smarter Navigation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smarter-navigation/)